# Using API Manager 1.9.1 with DAS 3

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible use API Manager 1.9.1 and DAS 3?
If yes, this configuration is like BAM configuration? or Is there any diference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two configurations are almost same. you can configure APIM 1.9.1 with BAM using [1] and you can configure with DAS [2] using WSO2 documenations.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+WSO2+BAM
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+WSO2+DAS